# Guardar Prints de una Funcion dentro de un txt, Python

Tags: python, tkinter, scraping

Buen dia, Estoy tratando de guardar muchos prints que tengo en una funcion dentro de bloc de notas.
Mi codigo es sobre web scraping y uso dos funciones para tener mas ordenado todo.
Dejo ejemplo.

```
def Primer_funcion():
 todo el web scraping

def Segunda_funcion():
 todo los prints

boton = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Compila pls",command=Primera_funcion, width="30", height="2")
```

El boton(tkinter) utiliza la primera funcion e imprimia todo dentro de un bloc de notas del mismo tkinter. Pero ahora quiero guardarlo todo en un bloc de notas de la pc.

Intente poniendo el codigo clasico para escribir dentro de un bloc de notas dentro de la primera funcion,pero no me funcionó, Me pidio que debe ser `str`, Lo puse y me imprimía `None`

```
def Primer_funcion():
 todo el web scraping

 file = open("C:\\Users\\acalobish\\Desktop\\caps.txt","w")
 file.write(str(Segunda_Funcion()))
 file.close()

def Segunda_funcion():
 todo los prints

boton = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Compila pls",command=Primera_funcion, width="30", height="2")
```

Como lograría guardar todo dentro de un bloc de notas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para escribir dentro de un archivo, tambien podrías utilizar la función print.

Si miras el prototipo, te vas a dar cuenta que tiene un argumento llamado `file`.

```py
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

Si abres tu archivo, podrías cambiar ese argumento y escribir en tu archivo. Por ejemplo:

```py
f = open("texto.txt", "w")
print("Un texto se escribirá", file=f)
f.close()
```

Por otro lado, en tu "forma clasica", necesitas que la función retorne un valor. Una función en python que NUNCA retorna un valor, va a evaluarse como `None`.

Tendrías que crear un string y concatenar todos los valores, y retornarlo. Para que en la función 1 te los escriba al archivo.

Espero que te sea útil. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por responder, Hice tu ejemplo. Sin Embargo no guarda los valores de rangos determinados dentro de un for, Por ejemplo. del 1 al 10, y se aumentara un numero cada 2 segundos. Entonces solo se imprime el 10. Mas no el 1,2,3,etc. Sabes alguna solucion a eso?. Gracias.

Comment: De casualidad, ¿no estás abriendo el archivo (y cerrandolo) en cada bucle for?
Recuerda que cuando abres un archivo en modo escritura (`w`) siempre el contenido será reemplazado por uno nuevo.

Comment: Si, Con el close, Acabo de probar sin el close. Pero de igual forma de reemplaza en cada bucle.

Comment: El archivo debes abrirlo fuera del bucle.

Comment: La mejor solución parece ser la propuesta por RicharlyxD del parametro `file` de la función `print`. Al parecer el problema es que las impresiones son resultados en el terminal y no retornos de función. Como se indica, la Segunda_funcion tiene "todos los prints" y cuando invocas str(Segunda_funcion) esta intentando convertír a `str` el retorno de la función Segunda_funcion, pero esta no retorna nada sino que imprime... supongo.

Comment: @LuisMunoz Gracias por la explicación, Ahora entiendo porque no funcionaba. :)